# Mysql order items by the newest of 2 dates

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with 2 dates - the ADDDATE and UPDATEDATE.
When an item is added, the ADDDATE is the current date and the UPDATEDATE is 0000-00-00.

I need to `ORDER BY` the SQL command and get the best date of those 2.
For example if ADD=12/1/2010 and UPDATE=30/6/2010,
the UPDATE DATE is best (newest).

Any advice?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) to find the newest date:

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(UPDATEDATE, ADDDATE)
```

Comment: Just a tip for people that had the issue I did, If you need to compare a timestamp and a MySQL date, you can also do
      ORDER BY GREATEST(ADDDATE, FROM_UNIXTIME( UPDATEDATE)  )

Comment: A gotcha is "returns NULL if any argument is NULL". Better to use the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3264962/6001

Answer (score 18):

```
 ORDER BY IF(UPDATEDATE > ADDDATE, UPDATEDATE, ADDDATE)
```

Comment: This works better than GREATEST when NULLs are possible and you want the non-null value returned.

Comment: you save my day

Answer (score 11):

If you want to make your database scalable, the best approach will be to add a new column `LATESTDATE` along with an insert/update trigger which sets that to the latest of the two candidate fields using, for example, [greatest](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).

Running per-row functions on your selects slows down very fast as the table gets bigger. If you want performance to stay workable as the table grows, this sort of trick is a common one.

It technically violates 3NF since it duplicates one of the dates but violation is okay for performance reasons and you still maintain the ACID properties because the triggers dictate that the columns stay consistent.

I don't know the MySQL trigger syntax off the top of my head but I would do something like:

- Create the new column, setting it to a suitable default value.
- Create the insert/update triggers to ensure changes will be reflected.
- Touch all the rows with a query like `update TBL set ADDDATE = ADDDATE` so that the trigger fires for all current rows.

The advantage this solution has is that it moves the cost of calculation to the time when data *changes,* not every single time you query the database. This amortises the cost across all reads, making it more efficient (unless you're one of those very rare beasts where the table is written more often than read).

Keep in mind this may not be necessary if the size of your table is relatively small - I work in environments where the tables are truly huge.