# MYSQL Combine Two Date Fields And Then Order BY

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 tables in MYSQL that will be joined by a foreign key. Each table has its own date field. What I would like to do is combine these two date fields together and then order by the combined information. I understand that you can order by multiple fields but I don't think that combines them.

**Example**

```
Join by tickets.ticket_id = ticket_history.ticket_id
```

Table 1

ticket_date

Table 2

ticket_history_date

Goal combine the two date fields and then order the rows by the combined dates

Comment: How do you want to combine them? Can you give us an example?

Comment: What do you mean by combine? Are the 2 dates always the same? If not how are you going to combine 2 dates? If they are the same, there isn't a need to combine them, just order by 1 of them and it will order by the other...no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume that you want the latest of the two dates, you can do something like this

```
SELECT
    [some info],
    GREATEST( ticket_date, ticket_history_date ) as latest_date
FROM
    [tables and join]
ORDER BY
    latest_date
```

If you wanted the oldest date you could use [LEAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) rather than GREATEST. If one of the dates might be NULL then you might want to look into [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: Another answer found here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264941/mysql-order-by-2-dates  ORDER BY GREATEST(1,2)

Answer (score 1):

The UNION query allows you to combine the result sets of 2 or more "select" queries. It removes duplicate rows between the various "select" statements.

Each SQL statement within the UNION query must have the same number of fields in the result sets with similar data types.

The syntax for a UNION query is:

select field1, field2, . field_n
from tables
UNION
select field1, field2, . field_n
from tables;