# Order data from database by two dates in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have a problem with ordering two dates in django model. I have a model which keep records of the document like below:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    document_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    document = models.FileField()
    date_of_signature = models.DateField()
    date_of_rectification = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_of_signature', '-date_of_rectification']
```

I have used the class Meta [`Options.ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering) to order date and got result with ordering, but my specific problem is that:

1. Ordering should be based on both fields if both fields have the date.
2. But `date_of_rectification` can be a `null` value, so if it is `null` then ordering must be with latest `date_of_signature` which I didn't get with class Meta `Options.ordering`

I have searched many questions on stackoverflow and found this MySQL query [Mysql order items by the newest of 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264941/mysql-order-items-by-the-newest-of-2-dates) which exactly solved my problem in MySQL database and implemented this query on django [Manager.raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) as below I got expected result. But this didn't help me on ordering data on **Django Admin** which is not my requirement. And also I want to know if this query could be solved using django Queryset insted of RawQueryset.

```
Model.objects.raw("""SELECT * FROM document
                ORDER BY IF(date_of_rectification > date_of_signature,
                date_of_rectification, date_of_signature)""")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out so many options I found a solution with which we can get the desired result using [conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) in django as below:

```
Document.objects.annotate(
    latest=Case(
        When(date_of_rectification__isnull=True, then=F('date_of_signature')),
        When(date_of_rectification__gte=F('date_of_signature'), then=F('date_of_rectification')),
        default=F('date_of_rectification')
    )
).order_by('-latest')
```

The MySQL query that django will translate this code will be as:

```
SELECT myapp_document.document_title, myapp_document.document,
       myapp_document.date_of_signature, myapp_document.date_of_rectification, 
       CASE WHEN myapp_document.date_of_rectification IS NULL THEN myapp_document.date_of_signature 
       WHEN myapp_document.date_of_rectification >= (myapp_document.date_of_signature) THEN myapp_document.date_of_rectification 
       ELSE myapp_document.date_of_rectification END AS latest FROM myapp_document ORDER BY latest DESC
```

But I am not sure how efficient is it. Hoping for some better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the query on the two fields, grabbing the greatest of the two:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest
Document.objects.annotate(
    latest=Greatest('-date_of_signature', '-date_of_rectification')
).order_by('-latest')
```

Regarding the ordering within the admin, you can override the `get_queryset` method to use the same annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)

    def queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(DocumentAdmin, self).queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = qs.annotate(
            latest=Greatest('-date_of_signature', '-date_of_rectification'))
        )
        return qs.order_by('-latest')
```

Alternatively, if the above doesn't work (for example, the null field handling isn't what you're going for) you could denormalize the two fields, creating a third one called `last_modified` which has `editable=False` and `db_index=True`. You can then compute it on `save()`. Ordering off of that field is going to be quite a bit more efficient query-wise at the expense of more database fields and a few additional lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for your response Robert. But this queryset didn't provide me the solution that I wanted rather its output was in random which I didn't know how it outputs. This same output behavior is also been achieved with `Document.objects.filter(date_of_rectification__gte=F('date_of_signature')`. Your answer to sort data during `save()` methods I think will be more convenient and will look on to it. If you have a solution regarding it then I will be happy to know it.